# Configuring memory allocation in mesos

Tags: hadoop, memory-management, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I'm running hadoop on mesos, and I'm unsure how to configure memory for mesos.  Specifically, a parameter like mapred.mesos.slot.mem (from https://github.com/mesos/hadoop/blob/master/configuration.md) would get configured in what file?

I know that other parameters in the configuration.md file can be placed in hadoop's mapred-site.xml file, but I don't know where to put other mesos configuration parameters.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.